# XElement returning Nothing from another XElement

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I have been absolutely stumped on this issue for hours. Basically I need to return an XElement from another XElement. I know for certain that the node I am looking for exists and is spelled correctly. Below is an abbreviated example of the source XML I am working with.

```
<PrintXmlFile  xmlns="http://www.samplenamespace.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Image>
        <AddedDate>2021-03-01T00:00:00</AddedDate>
    <Image>
    <Forms>
        <AddedDate>2021-03-01T00:00:00</AddedDate>
    </Forms>
</PrintXmlFile>
```

Literally all I want to do is return the Forms element and any child (if any). Below is an abbreviated version of my code.

```
      Private Sub StartProcessingXML(ByRef sourceXML As XElement)
    
        Dim formsXElement As XElement = sourceXML.Element("Forms")
       
      End Sub
```

When I step through the code formsXElement is always nothing. Based on what I've researched it should be this simple but that may not be the case. Could it be the fact that I need to incorporate the namespaces when searching through the source xml? If so, what is the best way to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is removing the namespace applicable?

Comment: If you can get rid of the namespace.

Comment: When you step through the code, you should start by looking at the contents of `sourceXML` to make sure that they are as you expect.  As an aside, `sourceXML` should be `ByVal` instead of `ByRef` because you are not re-assigning it in the routine.  Reference types have somewhat unintuitive behavior with `ByRef` and `ByVal` in VB; with a reference type (everything but built-in non-`String` types, `Enum`s, and `Structure`s) `ByVal` is passing a reference with a fixed target while `ByRef` is passing a reference with a changeable target.

Answer (score 0):

The input XML has a default namespace. Each and every XML element is bound to it.

Here is how to handle a default namespace.

**VB.NET**

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim xelem As XElement = XElement.Parse("<PrintXmlFile xmlns='http://www.samplenamespace.com'
              xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
        <Image>
            <AddedDate>2021-03-01T00:00:00</AddedDate>
        </Image>
        <Forms>
            <AddedDate>2021-03-01T00:00:00</AddedDate>
        </Forms>
    </PrintXmlFile>")

    Dim ns As XNamespace = xelem.GetDefaultNamespace()
    Dim formsXElement As XElement = xelem.Descendants(ns + "Forms").FirstOrDefault()
    Dim AddedDate As String = formsXElement.Element(ns + "AddedDate")?.Value

    Console.WriteLine(formsXElement)
    Console.WriteLine(AddedDate)
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
<Forms xmlns="http://www.samplenamespace.com">
  <AddedDate>2021-03-01T00:00:00</AddedDate>
</Forms>
2021-03-01T00:00:00
```